# Field 'name' in table 'oauth_access_tokens' is what used for?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have already searched, but no answers that I found.

Can I revoke all access tokens based on this same name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with multi-auth (smartins/passport-multiauth) so I'm giving you my 2 cents on your question.

In my `oauth_access_tokens`, I am surprised to see the `name` field is NULL for all my records so I don't think the `name` field is being used in Laravel 5.7

To revoke access token, you can

- set the `revoked` to 1
- delete row in `oauth_access_tokens`

you can use `client_id` with `user_id` to restrict which users and which client type (password grant, personal access ...) you want to revoke

Comment: In your opinion, which best method? set revoked to 1 or remove the token?

Comment: set revoked to 1 to keep the history intact.